# how to add rpath ORIGIN to shared library

Tags: cmake

I am building a shared library and i do not want to use the install path as i am just going to copy it locally.
I've tried the following but none of these rpath setting worked, which i think because they will only work when i actually do make install which i won't.

When i do make, i could see that cmake is setting my rpath to a absolute path to ~/develop/libA.so, rather than $ORIGIN. How to actually tell cmake to set it to ORIGIN? Thanks for help!

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH $ORIGIN)
set(CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH FALSE)


add_library(mylib SHARED
    test.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(mylib PRIVATE ~/develop/libA.so)
```

Update:
the only thing that worked so far is

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wl,-rpath,$ORIGIN")
```

cmake_exe_linker_flag is only used when making executables.
target_link_options and target_link_libraries does not parse '$' correctly and seems no way around it.

Correct me if im wrong. CMake is a myth without any examples in the doc.

Comment: `set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH $ORIGIN)`?

Comment: it only works when doing make install like i mentioned..

Comment: Then maybe `CMAKE_BUILD_RPATH_USE_ORIGIN` will help?